# Pivot cell values into columns using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

When running this query:

```
SELECT * FROM content_events
```

I get a table like this:

```
+------+-------------+
| hour | event_type  |
+------+-------------+
|    1 | loaded      |
|    2 | viewability |
|    3 | play        |
|    4 | loaded      |
|    1 | viewability |
|    2 | play        |
|    3 | loaded      |
|    4 | viewability |
|    5 | play        |
|    1 | loaded      |
|    2 | viewability |
+------+-------------+
```

And I'd like to pivot it so I get it this way:

```
+------+--------+------+-------------+
| hour | loaded | play | viewability |
+------+--------+------+-------------+
|    1 |      2 |      |           1 |
|    2 |        |    1 |           2 |
|    3 |      1 |    1 |             |
|    4 |      1 |      |           1 |
|    5 |        |    1 |             |
+------+--------+------+-------------+
```

To achieve this, should I first create a dummy column called value that contains "1" in each cell? In other words do a select like this:

```
SELECT *, 1 as value FROM content_events
```

which would return this:

```
+------+-------------+-------+
| hour | event_type  | value |
+------+-------------+-------+
|    1 | loaded      |     1 |
|    2 | viewability |     1 |
|    3 | play        |     1 |
|    4 | loaded      |     1 |
|    1 | viewability |     1 |
|    2 | play        |     1 |
|    3 | loaded      |     1 |
|    4 | viewability |     1 |
|    5 | play        |     1 |
|    1 | loaded      |     1 |
|    2 | viewability |     1 |
+------+-------------+-------+
```

and then use that table to do a pivot? If that assumption is correct, how would the pivot query be?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Looking forward to getting an answer! :)

Many thanks!

Comment: which rdbms, sql-server, oracle, mysql?  The answers will be different depending on your system.  Also note that sql-sever use PIVOT it is well documented.

Comment: @Matt thanks very much for the incredibly quick response. I'm using mysql workbench. I get this error when using your query: An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
SELECT *
FROM
    content_events e
    PIVOT (
    COUNT(event_type)
    FOR event_type IN (loaded,play,viewability)
) p

[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "PIVOT";
1 statement failed.

Execution time: 0.06s

Comment: PIVOT doesn't exist for mysql but you can do conditional aggregation instead see my updated answer for the method

Comment: All perfect now! Thanks a lot for spending some time on answering this. Very much appreciated @Matt :-)

Comment: your welcome if my answer worked for you please accept it if you are curious about how/when/why here is a link about it: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql/most rdbms's use conditional aggregation to do what you want.

```
SELECT
    hour
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN event_type = 'loaded' tHEN event_type END) as loaded
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN event_type = 'play' tHEN event_type END) as play
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN event_type = 'viewability' tHEN event_type END) as viewability
FROM
    content_events t
GROUP BY
    hour
ORDER BY
    hour
```

sql-server answer for you.  No need to add an additional 1 column

```
SELECT *
FROM
    content_events e
    PIVOT (
    COUNT(event_type)
    FOR event_type IN (loaded,play,viewability)
) p
```